# Dynamic Segmentation Error for segments in Geomedia Pro 2015

Tags: error, dynamic, geomedia, dynamic-segmentation

I have a couple of segments that I am trying to do Dynamic Segmentation on with **Geomedia Professional 2015**.

I am using the EXACT same Route IDs for the segments and the EXACT same Postmiles for beginning and end segments. I am receiving the error message:

> Unable to locate event.  No matching key or wrong type fields are in
>   the LRS dataset.

For one of the segments I created a new spreadsheet and even though the Route name is incorrect I got the segment to DynSeg.   I did that for the other two segments but it didn't work.

Will send segment database and jpg image of problems upon request.

Comment: Your question is pretty difficult to answer. I understand it because I have worked with DynSeg a lot in GM and it is difficult to explain. So if you are willing to share data I can try and help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145563)